# 3TB WD30EZRX is only recognized as an 1.8TB Disk - GPT formatted, UEFI-System - what can I do?

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, sata

Searched through the net for about 3h now, tested anything that seemed promising - but still no 3TB! And I don't mean no 3TB partition - the drive is actually detected as 1.8TB by various programs!

**GPT fdsik 0.8:**

```
Disk 1:: 3907073134 sectors, 1.8 TiB
Logical sector size: 512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 161388AB-0740-478D-AD58-17BF33D6517D
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 3907073100
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 3907073067 sectors (1.8 TiB)

No problems found. 3907073067 free sectors (1.8 TiB) available in 1
segments, the largest of which is 3907073067 (1.8 TiB) in size.
```

**WD DataLifeGuard - TestResults:**

```
Test Option: QUICK TEST 
Model Number: WDC WD30EZRX-00MMMB0  
Firmware Number: 80.00A80 
Capacity: 2000.42 GB
SMART Status: PASS 
Test Result: PASS 
Test Time: 06:03:22, November 24, 2012
```

And of course, Windows Diskmanagement shows also 1.863,04GB for this disk, although it is GPT formatted and has no partitions on it.

My System is a Windows 7 x64 on an ASUS Maximus V Formula with the UEFI-BIOS from 11/09/2012 v1408 (up-to-date). The disk is connected to one of the 6g Sata3 ports and has no jumpers set.

After all I've read, I would say this should work - but it doesn't.

What the heck is wrong?!

Comment: Is your BIOS providing some information about your HDD ?

Comment: It should actually work... Quick Workaround: Create two partitions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for clarification to anyone else having a simillar problem:

It was actually a malfunction of the hardware! Had to send the drive in.

After like 24h testing and trying every angle and tool available, there was just NOTHING indicating, that this would be a 3TB Drive.

New drive worked instantly. I have now two of this kind working properly since 8 months.

Sometimes it's just broken ;)